# Download link not working in android browser app

Tags: android, browser

Recently I created a simple Android browser app for my website. Everything is working fine but when I click on the download link it does not start downloading. Its .apk file is stored inside my server.

Downloading is working fine in other browsers like Chrome, Android browser and all others.

Here is my main-activity code.

```
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewapkapps);
    ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new OurViewClient());
    ourBrow.loadUrl("http://websitename .com");
    ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Please describe your concrete issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding DownloadListener will help you!

```
 {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewapkapps);
        ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new OurViewClient());
        ourBrow.loadUrl("http://websitename .com");
        ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      ourBrow.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                long contentLength) {

                                              Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
                        startActivity(intent);
                }
    }
```